# When editing a node, tab group titles are missing

Tags: 8, panels

When editing a node, tab group titles are missing:

[image: Missing Table Group Titles]

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="horizontal-tabs-list">
   <li class="horizontal-tab-button horizontal-tab-button-0 first selected" tabindex="-1"><a href="#edit-group-m"><strong></strong><span class="summary"></span><span id="active-horizontal-tab" class="visually-hidden">(active tab)</span></a></li>
   <li class="horizontal-tab-button horizontal-tab-button-1" tabindex="-1"><a href="#edit-group-content"><strong></strong><span class="summary"></span></a></li>
   <li class="horizontal-tab-button horizontal-tab-button-2" tabindex="-1"><a href="#edit-group-sidebar"><strong></strong><span class="summary"></span></a></li>
   <li class="horizontal-tab-button horizontal-tab-button-3 last" tabindex="-1"><a href="#edit-group-related-content"><strong></strong><span class="summary"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

So the titles are already not printed, so it is not a CSS issue.

Is this a known issue? How can I start debugging this?

Comment: Drupal 8 reached end of life in November 2021. Upgrade to Drupal 9.

Comment: @cilefen yes that is unfortunate, we are in the process of a relaunch, still it needs to be fixed for Drupal 8, if possible

Comment: Drupal 8 is directly upgradeable to Drupal 9. I would start by enabling template debugging and work backward from there.

Comment: Thanks, will try. We tried Upgrading to 9 but had issues. The above issue surfaced since we upgraded to the latest 8 version.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a bug in a contrib module and needs to be handled in the issue queue on drupal.org

Answer (score 1):

Updating `drupal/field_group` to 3.2.0 helped.